# Can this PCRE regex be converted to an equivalent Vim regex?

Tags: regex, vim

Can this PCRE regex be converted to an equivalent Vim regex?

`/(http\N+?),(\N+?),(\N+?),,(\X+?),(\N+?),(\N+?),0$/gm`

The regex was used on some test data at the wonderful https://regex101.com/ but I now need to make use of it.

I would like to use this regex in Python, but some of the options used are not available in Python, because Python AFAIK is not PCRE compliant.

I could use Perl or PHP, but I was wondering if it would be possible to convert the above regex to a Vim regex as a quick proof of concept for the rest of the data I have - which is a LastPass export as CSV (which is a nightmare due to many stray commas in `col5` the Notes field!).

The layout of the CSV file is:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| url | username | password | totp | extra | name | grouping | fav |

So the regex I'm looking to implement in Python would allow me to pick  out `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, ignore `col4`, `col5`, `col6`, `col7`, ignore `col8`.

Because `col5` can contain commas I thought to isolate those columns that don't contain commas first, leaving `col5` to be whatever is left between the other groups, using `,0$` as the end of entry marker - where `col5` can unfortunately span multiple lines and contain commas and almost any other characters.

I've asked if this can be done with Vim because I could change the CSV comma to be something that does not exist in the file presently and then be able to import the file without it exploding!

Ultimately I would like to do this in Python though, but that can wait if it can be done easily enough in Vim by replacing the CSV comma to something else.

Comment: Not sure if this is right, but give this a go: /\(http\%(\_[^,]\+\)\),\%(\_[^,]\+\),\%(\_[^,]\+\),,\%(\_[^,]\+\),\%(\_[^,]\+\),\%(\_[^,]\+\),0$

Comment: You can change the regex flavor to Python at regex101. Just select it from the list on the left.

Comment: https://pypi.org/search/?q=pcre , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcre+python , https://pypi.org/project/regex/ , https://pypi.org/project/re2/

Comment: Why the heavy use of `\N` instead of, say, `.`? Do you intend to match carriage returns?

Comment: It sounds like `/\v(http.{-}),(.{-}),(.{-}),,(.{-}),(.{-}),(.*),0$/`

Comment: @Kwright02 - I tried it, but it didn't work. What are the `%` and `_` for? Also, all the parenthesis need escaping unless you use \v - Thanks.

Comment: @CAustin - I did try that, but I built the regex using PCRE, switching to Python does not convert the regex for Python unfortunately, it only changes the regex engine being used. - Thanks.

Comment: @phd - Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @CAustin - Sorry didn't see your second comment. Yes, I need to match over multiple newlines. Basically to capture everything either side of a problematic field of CSV. :-(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Wow! That is almost perfect! Except, I need to isolate everything between the 4th comma from the left, and the 3rd comma from the right. The content between those two points can contain newlines also, and needs to be it's own group. - I half stumbled upon your version earlier while looking on [https://www.vimregex.com/](https://www.vimregex.com/) on how to do non-greedy captures. Awesome conversion. Would you mind putting your comment as an answer, and possibly address the missing component? - Much appreciated.

Comment: @AndroidControl `\N` matches non-newline characters (negation of `\n`), so I don't see how that would ever work for you if your input does contain newlines. Again, it looks like what you're after is `.`. Regarding switching the flavor of regex at regex101, I was suggesting that you use that to test your new pattern, not saying that it would convert your existing one.

Comment: @CAustin, sure, I understand, but the PCRE regex as it is, on regex101, works 99% - I just discovered an edge case, when there is no content in the troublesome column of CSV, it fails to match those lines correctly and breaks the current set of grouping - which is essential. :-/ - Re: regex101. Oh I see, the problem with that is that I couldn't get Python to work over multiple lines ignoring newlines. :-/

Comment: If you need to match across lines, you need to add ``\_`` before `.`. Something like `/\v(http.{-}),(.{-}),(.{-}),,(\_.{-}),(.{-}),(.*),0$/`. Do I understand it right, the `\X` meant to match across lines?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes. The `\X` is capturing everything that is between the left groups and the right groups.  The other columns either don't contain a comma, or are unlikely to contain a comma - but if they do I can mitigate that. Your amended regex covers more but also misses some. I can't easily tell if it's capturing too much and impacting on the other groups or what - I have no fancy colouring to be able to tell like on regex101 :-) - I'll add more details to the question to clarify more.

Comment: You must provide the exact example using the link to regex101.com. Without sample input text and expected output/behavior, it is difficult to help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I understand. I have added more details to the question. I will also try to create some sample content for regex101 that covers the scenarios that I have, or may encounter. To simplify things, I will assume that `col5` will be the only field to contain commas. I will have to manually deal with any fallout from that not being true anyway. - Thank you for your time and patience, much appreciated. :-) +1

Comment: Ok, I think you need `/\v(http[^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),,(\_.*),([^,]*),([^,]*),0$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Okay, that one misses entries in a slightly different way, and I can't see where any overlap may be either - I need to get some sample text so you can appreciate differences I am observing. Bare with me while I put some example together.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I think your previous regex might be right. I don't see inconsistent highlighting now - the highlighting of the previous one looked like it was overlapping. I think vim may have a bug in the regex highlighting. If I pgup/pgdn it un-highlights sections that were highlighted, looking like the regex hasn't captured what it previously did. If I single line scroll with the missing highlights it gets even worse, with more missing. If I pgup/pgdn to a fully highlighted screen, then go line by line it all looks okay again. I'm not sure if vim is lying to me now, hopefully not! :-/

Comment: If you provided some sample data that demonstrated your issues it would be far easier to ensure you have a working solution.

Comment: IMHO, converting a regex to a different dialect as a proof of concept is the wrong way to go. The Python code to verify the regex would have about three lines - much less effort than translating to Vim's regex dialect.

Comment: Do not forget to accept/upvote answers that solved your issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the pattern you want is

```
/\v(http[^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),,(\_.{-}),([^,]*),([^,]*),0$/
```

The point here is that you only match any text with the fourth group, all other groups only match characters other than a comma and thus cannot contain commas and stay within a single field.

- `\v` - very magic mode
- `(http[^,]*)` - Group 1: `http` and then zero or more chars other than a comma
- `,` - a comma
- `([^,]*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than a comma
- `,` - a comma
- `([^,]*)` - Group 3: zero or more chars other than a comma
- `,,` - two commas
- `(\_.{-})` - any zero or more chars as few as possible (`\_` makes `.` match newlines)
- `,` - a comma
- `([^,]*)` - Group 4: zero or more chars other than a comma
- `,` - a comma
- `([^,]*)` - Group 5: zero or more chars other than a comma
- `,0` - literal `,0` text
- `$` - end of line.

If you want to make sure you match from start of a line, add `^` after `\v`, i.e. `/\v^(http[^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),,(\_.{-}),([^,]*),([^,]*),0$/`